# How to make the recycler view not display the same data again? (Firebase)(AndroidStudio)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-recyclerview

My app retrieves data from a firebase database, saves the data in an array list and displays it in a recycler view.
Everything works fine except that when I add a new item the whole list gets displayed in the recycler view again.
So let's say before starting the app there have already been 3 items in the database and now I add another item to the database while I have the app open, the recycler view shows 7 items ( the three old ones twice, plus the new one).

How do I prevent that items are shown more than ones?

```
 reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {

                    ItemCard n = dataSnapshot1.getValue(ItemCard.class);
                    list.add(n);

                }
                 adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
                 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
          }

   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty the list before adding new items

Comment: I was wondering if there isn’t a more elegant solution.